# how to get key value of array with curl (php)

Tags: php, api, arrays, curl

I want to make use of an API but it print alot of info and i don't know how i can get a few key values of the array.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM kvk WHERE adres='Wit-geellaan 158'";
$host  = "http://api.openkvk.nl/php/";
$url   = $host ."/". rawurlencode($query);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Is my php script and it shows

```
array(array("RESULT"=>array("TYPES"=>array("int","bigint","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","int","int","smallint","smallint","int"),"HEADER"=>array("id","kvk","bedrijfsnaam","adres","postcode","plaats","type","kvks","sub","bedrijfsnaam_size","adres_size","verhuisd"),"ROWS"=>array(array("1303095","271242250000","Schoonmaakbedrijf Regio","Wit-geellaan 158","2718CK","Zoetermeer","Hoofdvestiging","27124225","0","23","16","0")))))
```

Thanks in advance

Greetings,
Vierri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Use the cURL setting to put the result into a variable rather than printing it    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

//store the result rather than print (as we set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ( $result === false ){
    //something went wrong, handle the error
}

//evaluate the array result and store it. (Please don't use this line in production code)
//as the $result string is from a untrusted source
eval('$array = '.$result.';');

//then you can, for example, get a list of the types
$types = $array[0]['RESULT']['TYPES'];


//or some keys
$keys = array_keys($array[0]['RESULT']);
```

The above code is **dangerous** and probably **shouldn't be used** as it is. They could put anything nasty in the response and you would evaluate it (the `eval` line) which could do bad things to your server. I would check if they have a better API that doesn't send responses in that format. (json or XML would be better)

If not you may want to considerer manually parsing the response array rather than using `eval`

Comment: Hello thnx for your response,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web/test.php(20) : eval()'d code on line 1

Warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array in /var/www/clients/client5/web6/web/test.php on line 27

is the error i get when i use the eval

Answer (score 0):

To get all keys and values:

```
$server_output = curl_exec($curl);
var_dump($server_output);
```

To just get a list of keys:

```
$server_output = curl_exec($curl);
ksort($server_output);
foreach ( $server_output AS $key => $val ) {
  echo "$key\n";
}
```

Comment: The response is a string not an array. `ksort` and `foreach` expect arrays.